# Pattern for querying term store

Tags: 2010, development, patterns-and-practices

Currently, I have a big and ugly helper class for getting data from the (SharePoint 2010) term store. I want to refactor this into something more robust and maintainable. Is there any design pattern I should use that is "best-practice"? I was thinking about the repository pattern, but currently I only read data, so that might not be what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 4 main patterns that are commonly used! between them mvp and repository are the most common, in you case i would belive the best option would be repository:

> •The Model-View-Presenter (MVP) Pattern
>
> •The Repository Pattern
>
> •The Service Locator Pattern
>
> •The Trusted Façade Pattern

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649977.aspx

The Repository Pattern

if you hit any of these points as i think you do than this is the one for you:

> Context In many applications, the business logic accesses data from
>   data stores such as databases, SharePoint lists, or Web services.
>   Directly accessing the data can result in the following:
>
> •Duplicated code 
>   •A higher potential for programming errors 
>   •Weak typing of the business data
>   •Difficulty in centralizing data-related
>   policies such as caching 
>   •An inability to easily test the business
>   logic in isolation from external dependencies Objectives  Use the
>   Repository pattern to achieve one or more of the following objectives:
>
> •You want to maximize the amount of code that can be tested with
>   automation and to isolate the data layer to support unit testing.
>
> •You access the data source from many locations and want to apply
>   centrally managed, consistent access rules and logic.
>
> •You want to implement and centralize a caching strategy for the data source. •You
>   want to improve the code's maintainability and readability by
>   separating business logic from data or service access logic.
>
> •You want to use business entities that are strongly typed so that you can
>   identify problems at compile time instead of at run time.
>
> •You want to associate a behavior with the related data. For example, you want to
>   calculate fields or enforce complex relationships or business rules
>   between the data elements within an entity.
>
> •You want to apply a domain model to simplify complex business logic.

more on the patterns can be found here:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/most-important-design-patterns-for-sharepoint-developers-.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look into these patterns, especially the repository pattern